# Refer To Controls in a Frame in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the `Class Module`, and I use it to handle `Click` event. I use `Macro3()` to link events with button on the Frame `T1` and it works.

I have hundred of Frames (ActiveX Control) with names like `T1,T2,T3...`.

How do I reference the controls in each frame? I tried `ActiveSheet.Shapes("T1").Controls("title_pic_tog")`. It doesn't work. If we can make this work then I can use a variable to replace `Shapes("t1")`.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents cBox As MSForms.ToggleButton

Private Sub cBox_Click()
    msgbox("clicked")
    'End If
End Sub

Sub Macro3()
    Set title_pic_tob_Event_Coll = New Collection

    Set title_pic_tob_Event = New titlepictog
    Set title_pic_tob_Event.cBox = ActiveSheet.t1.Controls("title_pic_tog")
    title_pic_tob_Event_Coll.Add title_pic_tob_Event
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Class Module (Say `Class1`)

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cBox As MSForms.ToggleButton

Private Sub cBox_Click()
    MsgBox ("clicked")
End Sub
```

In a Module

```
Dim TBArray() As New Class1

Private Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Integer, FrmBCtl As OLEObject, TBCtl As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet2

    '~~> Loop through all objects in the worksheet
    For Each FrmBCtl In ws.OLEObjects
        '~~> Check if the oleobject is a frame
        If TypeName(FrmBCtl.Object) = "Frame" Then
            '~~> Loop through all controls in the frame
            For Each TBCtl In FrmBCtl.Object.Controls
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve TBArray(1 To i)
                Set TBArray(i).cBox = TBCtl
            Next TBCtl
        End If
    Next FrmBCtl

    Set FrmBCtl = Nothing
    Set TBCtl = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]