# VBA Excel Activex Frame control containing option buttons, the buttons disappear when I leave Design Mode

Tags: excel, vba, controls, activex, frame

I am developing a quotation process with VBA in an Excel Worksheet. I placed an ActiveX Frame control with 2 option buttons inside.
As soon as I leave Design Mode, the buttons disappear. I have made sure the buttons are visible, have the correct width and height and I know they are there because I can access them pragmatically.
The problem is, I guess, with the Frame control that probably has a bug.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, EOutlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an option button to your frame, right-click the frame and choose "Frame object >> Edit" - add the option button from the toolbox which pops up, not from the Developer ribbon.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I have already received this advice. The problem I get into is that the option button is NOT available typing code Sheet1.optCreateClient..... it can't be seen. Another problem I get into is adding code to the option button. I don't know how to do it. Any other suggestion? thanks,

Comment: Looks like adding code to the controls in the frame needs to be done dynamically - eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341254/refer-to-controls-in-a-frame-in-worksheet

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim, I will check on it.