# Accessing controls within worksheet embedded Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame

Tags: vba, forms, controls, frame

I need to know how to access the controls placed within a frame control I placed directly into a worksheet...

Per the suggestion of another Q&A site, I added a Frame Control to a worksheet by using Developer>Insert>More Controls>Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame, then right clicking the frame>Frame Object>Modify to add a bunch of textboxes, comboboxes, and command buttons the same way I would when creating a userform.

However, after spending forever designing this thing, I am finding that accessing/manipulating the controls I placed is much more difficult than utilizing a userform. The point of having an embedded form was to have the same functionality as a userform, while avoiding utilizing an additional userform, since I already have a pretty comprehensive userform in a separate workbook that will eventually interact with the workbook in question.

The point of my workbook is to have a data entry form that fills a dynamic table below the frame I placed. I have, for instance, several command buttons within that frame control that I can't seem to access to write the code to have the embedded textbox/combobox values fill the table.

Microsoft Co-pilot does not seem to understand my requests for how to correctly access the controls within the embedded frame control so I am hoping someone here will. (sorry so long-winded)

OLEObjects do not seem to work properly, and I cannot get a clear picture of how Shapes work. Regardless, none of those give me an option to use a simple Private/Public Sub CommandButton_Click() event that a userform would use.

I have attempted to use/manipulate OLEObjects with not much cooperation from intellisense, so I am unsure how to refer to the control values. I have had no luck figuring out how to create or simulate a commandbutton_click event to even start the code.

If I am in design mode and inside Frame Object>Modify, I do not have the option to view code if I right-click the button. Also, if I exit design mode, I can left click on the button and see it is being clicked, but I get no options whatsoever if I right-click. I tried setting the Frame's Locked property to False and still no functionality of the controls except left-click does work to enter the cursor/select options from the comboboxes, etc

Comment: Have you tried using the WorkSheet Shapes collection - example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973711/excel-vba-how-do-i-refer-to-a-form-control-on-a-worksheet

Comment: @Chill60 Yes I have. The first problem is that I have no controls to perform events on like CmdEnter_Click, to be able to even write the code and play with the control properties. No controls in Object (module window) to designate a procedure in the first place

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341254/refer-to-controls-in-a-frame-in-worksheet has an answer to this problem.

Comment: ...and do you really *need* that frame?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513155) looks promising.